# JQuery - what is the best way to fire a MVC controller action via JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Basically, I have several Radio Buttons in a filtering column.  For example, if I am in the \Catalog\Flooring\Harwood section I have Radio Buttons for [Area Rugs], [Carpet] & [Stone & Tile].  So, what I want to do, instead of embedding an  tag under the Radio Button I'd like to fire a JQuery event and do a regular post back to the server.  I am thinking that $.post() should do it but I've not got it working correctly.

PS:  Anyway to embed/include the jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js file in my JS file so I get full intellisense?

Comment: Regarding intellisense if you're in an external javascript file just include the following line at the top of the file file:-

/// <reference path="jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc.js" />

Alternatively you can drag the vsdoc file from solution explorer into the edit window and visual studio will sort it out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Bind actions...
    $("#Navigation li[title]").live("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault; this.blur(); return updateNavigation($(this).attr('title')); });
    $("#ItemsPerPage").change(function(e) { return updatePaging(); });

    $('input[name=ProductType]').click(function() { return updateRadio(); });  //{ $('form#typeForm').submit(); });
    $(":checkbox").change(function(e) { return updateCheck(); });
});
```

Respond to the ProductType radio button event:

```
function updateRadio() {
    var productGroup = $("#valProductGroup").attr('title');
    var productType = $("input:radio[checked]").val();
    var url = "/Catalog/" + productGroup + "/" + productType;

    window.location = url;
    return false;
}
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ajax call to move an item up and down using an MVC controller action:

```
    [ActionName("item-reorder")]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public string ItemReorder(Guid id, string direction)
    {
        ReorderDirection dir = (ReorderDirection)Enum.Parse(typeof(ReorderDirection), direction, true);
        int newSequence = this.WebServiceProxy.MoveItem(id, dir);
        if (newSequence >= 0)
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ajax:Success"];
        else
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Ajax:Fail"];
    }
```

and the javascript:

```
AjaxMoveItem: function(row, direction) {
    //get the id from the attribute
    var itemId = row.attr('itemId');
    //update server
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/item-reorder',
        //data: ({ id: itemId, direction: direction }), //didn't work .. vars passed as null
        data: ({ id: itemId, direction: direction }),
        success: function(responseText) {
            if (responseText == 'success') {

                alert('moved');
            } else {
                alert('error: ' + responseText);
            }
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('unknown error');
        }
    });
},
```

Comment: Very nice and something I may use later on another page.  Right now I am trying to figure out to execute a very simple GET or POST so a new page is displayed.

Comment: Yep the idea was that this example shows you the different facets of posting to an MVC action. Your action would need to return your original View with the data filtered by the posted argument. Consider direction in the example being the filter value from the radio button and the responseText being the HTML of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GET -- this would do a get of /Catalog/Flooring/Harwood/

```
$(function() {
   $('input[type=radio]').click( function() {
       location.href = '<%= Url.Action( "Harwood", "Catalog/Flooring" ) %>' + '/' + $(this).val();
   });
});

<input type='radio' id='rugsRadio' name='typeRadio' value='AreaRugs' />
<input type='radio' id='carpetRadio' name='typeRadio' value='Carpet' />
...
```

Or you could use a POST -- this would do a post of /Catalog/Flooring/Harwood with the selected typeRadio as a form parameter:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name=typeRadio]').click( function() {
        $('form#typeForm').submit();
    });
});

<% using (Html.BeginForm("Flooring","Catalog", new { id = "Harwood" })) { %>
    <input type='radio' id='rugsRadio' name='typeRadio' value='AreaRugs' />
    <input type='radio' id='carpetRadio' name='typeRadio' value='Carpet' />
    ...
<% } %>
```

Comment: This looks nice and I am trying to figure out how to apply it to my situation.

Flooring is one of many ProductGroups.
Hardwood is one of many ProductTypes - a child of ProductGroup.

I store ProductGroup in a hidden control and the RadioButton(selected) would be the target ProductType.

It looks like you are embedding the code (2nd example) directly in the form.  Is this correct?

Comment: My route looks like:
routes.MapRoute(
    "CatalogType",
    "Catalog/{group}/{type}",
    new { controller = "Catalog"
        , action = "Types"
        , group = ""
        , type = "" }
);

Comment: Where do you get form#typeForm from?